# kendo chart zoomable not working

Tags: kendo-ui, zooming, pan

I have implemented kendo chart (column) on my html page.
I found that there is zoomable and pannable properties available for kendo chart.
Its not working on my side. here is what I have done so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Chartdata = [];
    var columndt = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: true,
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/43u4i",
        async: false
    }).success(function (result) {
        var dataresult = result;
        $(dataresult).each(function (e, data) {
            Chartdata.push({
                "date": new Date(Date.parse(data.date)),
                "close": data.close,
                "volume": data.volume,
                "high": data.high,
                "low": data.low,
                "open": data.open,
                "symbol": data.symbol
            });
        });
        $(Chartdata).each(function (e, data) {
        columndt.push({
            date: new Date(Date.parse(data.date)),
            value: data.volume,
        });
    });
    });

$("#Colchart").kendoChart({
        series: [{
            type: "column",
            field: "value",
            categoryField: "date"
        }],
        categoryAxis: {
            baseUnit: "second",
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        valueAxis: {
            line: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        dataSource: {
            data: columndt
        },
        pannable:
        {
            lock: "y"
        },
        zoomable: {
            mousewheel: {
                lock: "y"
            },
            selection: {
                lock: "y"
            }
        }
    });
    });
```

```html
<link href="http://kendochart.webashlar.com/kendochart/Stylesheets/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://kendochart.webashlar.com/kendochart/Stylesheets/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://kendochart.webashlar.com/kendochart/Javascripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendochart.webashlar.com/kendochart/Javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Colchart"></div>
```

What is the mistake i am making?

Thank you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Maharshi/8rukm6ou/ here is fiddler link, could not add in question section.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong version of KendoUI.  The pan and zoom was just introduced in the v2015.3.930 release that cam out in the lase 2 weeks.  You need to update your javascript references to the newer version.

See the what's new section:  http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui

Comment: I think Its updated version zoomable feature is available in the Js file that I am using. this is my version "Kendo UI v2015.2.902" also zoomable is available in it. you can find it in _initScroller function. Can you please check for me?

Comment: @MaharshiPrabhakar, you need version 2015.3.930